# Android emulator doesn't run from Android Studio on Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio for the first time and when i try to emulate a Nexus 5X with the API being 25 and the target being Android 7.1.1(Google API's) and the CPU being x86_64 on MacBook Pro with 16 GB RAM.

I can create the AVD image sucessully but when i click on emulate it does displays a bar with progress totally completed i.e the Emulator but doesn't spin up the Emulator.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I was running docker all the time along with it. I had to quit docker and then it did work.

Answer (score 4):

Are you running docker? If so quit the docker. They are using same port and can no be run at the same time.